# How to check if the CapsLock key is pressed? using C code or assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86-16, osdev, capslock

I am programming an operating system and I want to handle the instruction. The code prints to the screen the letters pressed but I don't know how to check if the CapsLock key is pressed. I assume there is a port that contains its state.
I have a function that can return the value of a port:

```
uint8_t port_byte_in (uint16_t port) {
    uint8_t result;
    asm("in %%dx, %%al" : "=a" (result) : "d" (port));// Inline assembler syntax
    return result;}
```

I someone can help me find the needed port or have another idea of how to check if the CapsLock key is pressed that would be great : )

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, answering: What did your research on the interface between your computer and the keyboard reveal? What hardware is it? Why do you expect the hardware to manage the CapsLock state?

Comment: Method how to test the current state of Caps/Num/Scroll locks in DOS and Windows see https://euroassembler.eu/prowin32/locktest.htm 
BiosAPI INT=16h,AH=2 in DOS, or WinAPI GetKeyState in MS Windows.

Answer (score 2):

> I assume there is a port that contains its state.

No:

For the hardware, the Caps Lock key is just a key like other keys (e.g. "A").

However, the software (e.g. the BIOS) reacts on the Caps Lock key differently:

Whenever you press the key, it changes the value of a "variable" from true to false or vice versa. Then it sends a command to the keyboard that the LED shall be switched on or off.

Your system will have to do this!

Communication with the keyboard (both reading the keys and setting the LEDs) is done using ports. However, it is much more complicated than you think.

You may have a look at the information about the [keyboard itself](https://wiki.osdev.org/PS/2_Keyboard) and about the [keyboard controller](https://wiki.osdev.org/%228042%22_PS/2_Controller) on the OSDev website.

The BIOS stores the information if Caps Lock is active [in bit 6 of the byte at address 40:18 (hex)](https://stanislavs.org/helppc/bios_data_area.html).

You can use this information when your system starts up.

Comment: I don't know the details, but there's been at least 3 different PC keyboard interface standards over the years. Which one does this answer apply to, PS/2? USB would be the most common nowadays, I would imagine.

Comment: @Lundin You are right. However, I think that the user will run his code on some virtual machine; and these machines typically simulate a PS/2 keyboard. I doubt that the user is able to access an USB keyboard low-level.

Comment: @Lundin: Given the [x86-16] [osdev] tags, I think we should assume this is about a toy OS that will run on an IBM-PC compatible, using (probably emulated) legacy hardware interfaces and maybe BIOS calls.  e.g. via a BIOS option for USB-legacy to expose it via PS/2 I/O ports.  (Chipsets support hooking those I/O ports via SMM, allowing BIOSes to maintain backwards compat with truly ancient hardware.)

Comment: @PeterCordes That's kind of the point, such old computers would have an even earlier version of the keyboard. Them big round connectors, I don't even know what the interface was called.

Comment: @Lundin: I think the connector was called AT keyboard.  I thought the software-visible interface was the same for those, though.  I don't remember ever seeing anything about software differences for keyboards for actual first-gen IBM PC vs. what modern PCs emulate in legacy mode.  (Not that I've gone looking, but I'm sure it would have come up on SO or in https://wiki.osdev.org/Category:Human_Interface_Device - but actually there's only a page for PS/2 keyboards, not for any other kind of keyboard.)